# Haskell-like type system in C

Tags: c, haskell, low-level, type-safety, type-systems

I was wondering, is it possible to integrate haskell's powerful type system into a language like C, and still be able to do efficent low level programming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There have been attempts to create low-level languages which use advanced type systems to make low-level programming safe. Those type systems are often actually even more advanced than Haskell's and allow things like ensuring at compile-time that pointers are accessed safely and arrays are not accessed out of bounds.

One such language is [ATS (Applied Type System)](http://www.ats-lang.org/) which besides many of Haskell's type system features also supports linear and dependent types.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently stumbled upon something related:

[The Habit Programming Language](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4205) (lambda-the-ultimate.org)

It's a dialect of Haskell, but geared towards low-level systems programming.

Answer (score 1):

See also [BitC](http://www.bitc-lang.org/), a language being developed to build a formally verified capability secure operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the goal of Mozilla's http://www.rust-lang.org/